# Not retrieving values out of input fields with javascript for database inserts

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So, first and foremost, I'm going to list the 3 sections of code that I'm referencing.

HTML:

```
<div id='newuserpage'>

    <h1><font color='white'>Create New User</font></h1>

    <div id='userbody'>
        <div id='userfields'>
            <div id='usernamelabel'>
                <font color='white'>Enter Username:</font>
                <input id='createfield1' type='text'>
            </div>

            <div id='passwordlabel'>
                <font color='white'>Enter Password:</font>
                <input id='createfield2' type='password'>
            </div>

            <div id='usertype'>
                <br>
                <font color='white'>User Type:</font>
                <select name="typeofuser" id='type'>
                    <option value="2">Student</option>
                    <option value="1">Teacher</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        <button id = 'newuserbutton' onclick='createuser()'>
            Submit
        </button>

        <button id = 'backtomenu' onclick = 'backtomenu()'>
            Back to Teacher Menu
        </button>
```

Javascript Function

```
function createuser()
{
var newuser;
var newpass;

// check browser type
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


newuser = document.getElementById("createfield1").value;
newpass = document.getElementById("createfield2").value;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {

        if (xmlhttp.responseText == '1') { //Connected properly
            var createdmessage= document.getElementById('createdmessage');
            createdmessage.style.visibility= 'visible';
        }
        if (xmlhttp.responseText == '2') {
            var loginpage = document.getElementById('loginbox');
            loginpage.style.display = 'block';
            }
         else {
            // show error message
            loginlabelerror.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}

// call php function
xmlhttp.open("GET","createuser.php");
xmlhttp.send("username=" + encodeURIComponent(newuser) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(newpass));

//var createdmessage= document.getElementById('createdmessage');
//createdmessage.style.visibility= 'visible';

}
```

PHP page to handle Insertion

```
<?php

$q=$_GET["username"];
$p=$_GET["password"];
$t=$_GET["type"];

$host="xxx"; // Host name 
$username="xxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxx"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$link)or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, type) VALUES('".$q."', '".$p."', 2)";

$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(! $retval)
{
    echo 2;
}

    echo 1;

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The problem I'm running into is that it's never actually pulling the values out of the createfield1 and createfield2 input areas. It just throws empty strings into the database.

(Ignore the drop down menu, That's something that we were toying around with but don't really need.)

As far as I can tell and can find online, what I've done SHOULD work? Unless I've completely misinterpreted something, I'm baffled as to why it's not actually retrieving the values that are entered into the input fields.

For demonstration purposes for an external source, I WANT blank fields to be allowed as essentially a "passthrough" where it doesn't actually do anything. The problem at hand is that even with an example of:

asdf

1234

entered into the two input fields, when the button calls the function to send the info over to be inserted, it doesn't pull those values, and instead just uses blank strings. I wouldn't expect value checking to be NEEDED for it to not use empty strings instead, one would think it should pull the values in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, creation events should always be post, not get. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp (there are more reputable sources out there but even they agree)

More importantly... Modify your send call..

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","createuser.php");
```

to be

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","createuser.php?username=" + encodeURIComponent(newuser) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(newpass));
```

You still need to call the send method.

Consider doing a post request instead: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

The number one reason for post/get, at least to me, is that get can be re-ran with no prompt. Post will at least warn the user and when it comes to account creation, a warning is in order.

Comment: Mmm I understand the point of using Post vs. Get, this is just a continuation I was working on for something a prior student wrote and I was trying to expand upon. Figured for readability I'd leave it the same, however I'll probably change it at some point.